# How can i check for image's orientation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios

I am working on a project where i need to upload photo to canvas but the problem is arising that when user uploading image from iphone, image is automatically getting rotated 90deg.

Is there any way i can check image's orientation using Javascript? and if i can rotate image if its orientation is not Normal(Horizontal)?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The device that takes the picture that it actually has a sensor that can tell orientation.

Using `window.orientation` we can get orientation either portrait or landscape

Refer

[How do I correctly detect orientation change using javascript and Phonegap in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io)

[How to extract image orientation information from image loaded in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632356/how-to-extract-image-orientation-information-from-image-loaded-in-canvas)