# How to read any image's orientation information if EXIF data doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to read any image's orientation in .net. I am trying to read this information through extracting orientation property from Exif data.

```
 public enum ExifOrientations
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        TopLeft = 1,
        TopRight = 2,
        BottomRight = 3,
        BottomLeft = 4,
        LeftTop = 5,
        RightTop = 6,
        RightBottom = 7,
        LeftBottom = 8,
    }

    // Return the image's orientation.
    public static ExifOrientations ImageOrientation(Image img)
    {
        const int OrientationId = 0x0112;

        // Get the index of the orientation property.
        int orientation_index =
            Array.IndexOf(img.PropertyIdList, OrientationId);

        // If there is no such property, return Unknown.
        if (orientation_index < 0) return ExifOrientations.Unknown;

        var orientationValue = img.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId).Value[0]; 
        // Return the orientation value.
        return (ExifOrientations)
            img.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId).Value[0];
    }
```

But I found many images don't have EXIF data for orientation, in that case, what is the best way to get an image's orientation.

[image]

This image doesn't have any orientation data. But below picture I think gives wrong orientation data or I misunderstood.

[image]

How is this image's orientation can be "TopLeft" as it's determined by the above code?

I need to know is there any other way of getting the image's orientation data if EXIF data doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract image orientation information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632356/).

Answer (score 1):

There's not really any perfect way to detect orientation without EXIF data. Systems that do this either use the dimensions of the image or detect content in the image.

[This answer has a good breakdown on the different option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18643802/11580377) and [And this answer has a great JavaScript function for detecting the orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490603/11580377).