# Image rotating in img tag

Tags: html, reactjs, image, azure

When you go directly to the image URL the image is not rotated, but within the image tag the image is rotated.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-beaver-zvfp2

I'm not sure what is going on

(I use Azure to host images)

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening to all images then you can simply add a transform css tag to rotate the image 90 degrees

eg:-

```
    style={{
      height: "500px",
      borderRadius: "15px 15px 15px 15px",
      boxShadow: "0px 5px 15px -4px #000000",
      transform:"rotate(90deg)",  <-----
    }}
```

Comment: I think the issue is that if it's shot on portrait on a mobile phone it does this? Because all the other photos that I have don't exhibit the same issue

Comment: JPEG image files contain meta-data that describes the original orientation of the images, browsers do not support this yet.

Comment: Please check this for further alternatives. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18643802/5074540

Comment: Thanks @harryManoharan! I used this http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi and the EXIF data shows Oreintation at 90 CW.