# imgkit get height of image

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, imgkit

what I'd like to do is very simple. I have a code which uses a imgkit library to load some webpage image and then stores it. It looks like that:

```
kit = IMGKit.new(site, :quality => 5, :width => 1024)
img = kit.to_img(:png)
file = kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/public/images/#{s2}.png")
```

I need to know the image height after loading in order to stretch canvas element behind it. Is there a way I can get the height ? Or if not, how could I achieve this without knowing the image height before loading, javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. Mini_magick gem was a fine way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327959/get-height-and-width-dimensions-from-base64-png),

Would following work?

```
kit = IMGKit.new(site, :quality => 5, :width => 1024)
img = kit.to_img(:png)
file = kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/public/images/#{s2}.png")  

var img2 = new Image();       
img2.onload = function(){
  var height = img2.height;

  //do all remaining processing here

};
img2.src = file;
```

Comment: i forgot to add that i use rails, you mixed code from rails and js into one... maybe i could get the height using minimagick_gem, but I have not yet tried